# Makefile match wildcard prerequisites for a rule

Tags: makefile

I want to pass some recipes to a makefile, like `comp1.mt comp2.mt comp3.mt` and have the makefile agregate them into a single list of MTs (it could also be `mt.compN`) to run them in bulk.

```
%.mt:
    @echo $* >> list_of_mts.txt

mt: %.mt
    @cat list_of_mts.txt
```

I want to pass these recipes in any order to the makefile so the specific case of calling `make comp1.mt comp2.mt mt` is not desirable.

Comment: Why you decided to use makefile here? simple one-liner script seems to do the same as you want: `echo "$@" | tr " " "\n" > list_of_mts.txt && cat list_of_mts.txt`

Comment: I do not understand the last sentence of your question: "_I want to pass these recipes in any order to the makefile so the specific case of calling `make comp1.mt comp2.mt mt` is not desirable._". Can you please explain?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet If I call `make comp1.mt comp2.mt mt` locally it seems to work as I exept, first the `compN` is called AND THEN `mt`, but that is because of the order i give in the arguments.

Comment: @Kuchara I know i could, but at this point, I am curious if there is a way for something like this to happen. ATM I am passing a variable to the makefile with the list of components.

Comment: @nemo9955 Sorry but what you want is still not clear. Do you want `make mt` to do all `something.mt`? If yes why do you invoke `make comp1.mt comp2.mt mt` and not just `make mt`? There are several problems with your Makefile but as your actual goal is not clear it is difficult to suggest solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why you need this implemented in makefile, but here you are:

```
MT_TARGETS:=$(filter %.mt,$(MAKECMDGOALS))

.PHONY: $(MT_TARGETS)
$(MT_TARGETS):
        @echo $@ | sed -e "s:.mt$$::" >> list_of_mts.txt

mt: $(MT_TARGETS)
        @cat list_of_mts.txt
```

Testing:

```
$ make mt comp1.mt comp2.mt comp3.mt
comp1
comp2
comp3
make: `comp1.mt' is up to date.
make: `comp2.mt' is up to date.
make: `comp3.mt' is up to date.
```

This is using special variable `MAKECMDGOALS`.

Note: list_of_mts.txt will grow endlessly...

Note2: writing to list_of_mts.txt is unsafe in parallel execution (the list_of_mts.txt file may get corrupted).

Comment: Thank you!
I actually didn't need a list as text, `$(MT_TARGETS): ;` and the list is made with `MT_TARGETS_RAW:=$(subst .mt_comp,,$(filter %.mt_comp,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))` and in the `mt:` i just use `@echo $(MT_TARGETS_RAW)`

Comment: But this is essentially the same as such script `echo "$@" | tr " " "\n" | sed -ne "s:.mt_comp$::p"`. If you can do something easier, do it! :-)

Comment: To prevent the paralelism issue, I did `@mkdir -p all_valit_mts/$(subst .mt_comp,,$@)` and the makefile is `mt : | clean_list_dirs $(MT_TARGETS)`.
The idea is, I want to keep it all as recipes, because I have a mechanism that can overwrite specific recipes like `comp1.mt_comp: ;` and with this approach I do not have change the part that skips actions.